# Run workflow on list or site - not on item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I would like to run workflow on list or on site. Not on a specific item.
Can I do it using only SharePoint Designer 2013?

Comment: Hi Nikita , It is possible to create workflows using SP Designer. Can you give us more info like what your requirement is ? What workflow that you want to do on your site or list ?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. 
I would like to send monthly email. I will use spd to create site workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use site workflows in sharepoint which can be used to track the site level events.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335710.aspx

http://amavs.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/sharepoint-2010-site-workflow/

http://sharepoint-videos.com/module-1/sp10create-a-site-workflow-and-modify-its-form-using-infopath/

As  most of these are 2010, but these would be also applicable for 2013.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your replay.I found it. 

can i schedule a site workflow ?

Comment: You can create a custom timer job and start that workflow programmatically. I will check if there is some other way for this.

Comment: can i use the existing timer job of SP ?

Comment: No, you have a create a custom one and write your custom logic within.